ETH under BSC Network instead of Erc20 to Phantom
I have sent ETH from Binance under BSC network to my Phantom Wallet instead of ETH Erc20 (ETH Network) and now I see my assets on BSCScan.com
How do I withdraw from there and get them back to my Binance account or Phantom wallet?
Any help?
Thanks!
